# Splitting Hibernate configuration files (hbm.xml files) when using subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

we have a hibernate mapping file (hbm.xml file) that maps a part of our domain to the database. This part contains a inheritance hierarchy. I.e. we have a parent class 'Parent' and several subclasses 'Child1', 'Child2', ...

Because of the structure of the hibernate mapping file the child classes are located within the parents `<class>` XML tag as `<joined-subclass>`.

Since this mapping file becomes larger and larger we now want to split it. Is there a way to have a mapping file for each subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag in the new XML:

```
<joined-subclass />
```

Or

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <subclass name="DomesticCat" extends="Cat" discriminator-value="D">
      <property name="name" type="string"/>
 </subclass>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Extracted from the hibernate site:

```
It is possible to define subclass, union-subclass, and joined-subclass mappings in separate mapping documents directly.
```

Ref: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Udo

Answer (score 0):

You can use ENTITY definitions in your XML:

In your main hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY subclass1 SYSTEM "classpath://my/hbms/subclass1.xml">
    <!ENTITY subclass2 SYSTEM "classpath://my/hbms/subclass2.xml">
    ]>

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="my.pkg.Parent">
         ...
         &subclass1;
         &subclass2;
</class>
```

And my/hbms/subclass1.xml:

```
<joined-subclass name="subclass1">
    <!-- all the subclass definitions -->
</joined-subclass>
```

And my/hbms/subclass2.xml:

```
<joined-subclass name="subclass2">
    <!-- all the subclass definitions -->
</joined-subclass>
```